# SQLExpress database file auto-creation error, Authorizing with Roles

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

The title kind of describes the problem. I am trying to use Role Authorization and I have successfully created users and roles. I can also assign roles to users. I have verified that the following actions do modify the database tables. However, I experience some sort of SQL Server timeout when I utilize Role Authorization on Controller methods.

For example:

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your admin page.";
        var context = new IdentityDbContext();
        IDbSet<IdentityRole> roles = context.Roles;
        List<string> roleList = new List<string>();
        foreach (IdentityRole role in roles)
            roleList.Add(role.Name);
        ViewBag.Roles = roleList;
        IDbSet<IdentityUser> users = context.Users;
        List<string> userList = new List<string>();
        foreach (IdentityUser user in users)
            userList.Add(user.UserName);
        ViewBag.Users = userList;
        return View();
    }
```

But this will time out with the response:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Below you can find my SQL connection string as well as the methods for creating a role and adding a user to a role. Thank you

SQL Connection String:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.10.160,1433;Initial Catalog=PriceConfigurator;User Id=PriceConfiguratorDBA;Password=*********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Role/User Managing:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToUser(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var userManager = new UserManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var context = new IdentityDbContext();
            var userName = collection["AddUserRoleUsername"];
            IdentityUser user = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
            var roleName = collection["AddUserRoleNameList"];
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
            return Json(userName + " added to " + roleName, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error occured: " + ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveFromUser(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var userManager = new UserManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var context = new IdentityDbContext();
            var userName = collection["RemoveUserRoleUsername"];
            IdentityUser user = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
            var roleName = collection["RemoveUserRoleNameList"];
            userManager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, roleName);
            return Json(userName + " removed from " + roleName, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error occured: " + ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
```

I've also tried to override the membership providers in my web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true">
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to check:

```
Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections:
    Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
    Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
    Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
    Enable local and remote connections
    Restart instance
```

You can also check this link [7 things to check to resolve "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…"](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

```
You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using:
    Start > Run > Firewall.cpl
    Click on exceptions tab
    Add sqlservr.exe
        typically located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQL\Bin - check your installs for the actual folder path
    Add the port (default is 1433)
    Check your connection string as well
Check if your SQL server services is up and running properly:
    Go to All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services
    Check to make sure SQL Server service status is Running.
Ensure that your remote server is in the same network:
    Open your command prompt and Run sqlcmd -L to ascertain if your server is included in your network list.
    See More At: [Using sqlcmd – Detect Installed SQL Server on Network][1]



Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration:
    Go to All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager > Select TCP/IP.
    Right click and select enable
```

You can also try this link [fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have verified the information you suggested. Also, I should point out that I can create users and roles just fine to this database. I can even use the [Authorize] property with no problem. The problems arise when I append the role property.